# Create and handle custom DOM attribute for all components / html tags

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I would like to create a custom attribute, which I would be able to use in any component or html tag (without modifying them), and this would run my function every time the page is rendered:

Example 1:

`<p myAttribute>Some text</p>`

Example 2:

`<div myAttribute size="2"></div>`

Handle somehow like this:

```js
register('myAttribute', (component) => {
  //access innerHtml from example 1, access 'size' attribute from example 2 etc...
 })
```

Is it possible to do this in React?

Comment: I know Vue.js and web component libraries like https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs can do this, don't know about React

Comment: Are you using Typescript?

Comment: Please add more explains about what are you trying to do